# PDO - UPDATE - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo un problema con un UPDATE, para simplificar los datos los llevo desde un formulario y ellos los paso como parametros a una funcion, hago el UPDATE y cuando hace el execute() me dice que si lo realizó, pero jamas hace la modificacion.

```
    global $conn;
    $producto = $conn->prepare
    ("UPDATE productos SET nombre = ?, precio = ?,
     marca = ?, presentacion = ?, stock = ? WHERE idproducto = ?");

    $producto->bindValue(1, $id);
    $producto->bindValue(2, $nombre);
    $producto->bindValue(3, $precio);
    $producto->bindValue(4, $marca);
    $producto->bindValue(5, $presentacion);
    $producto->bindValue(6, $stock);

   if($producto->execute())
    {
        $respuesta = "El articulo se actualizo con exito";
        header("location: ". BACK_END_URL ."/?rta=".$respuesta."&color=verde");
    }
   else
   {
       $respuesta = "El articulo no se actualizo con exito";
       header("location: ". BACK_END_URL ."/?rta=".$respuesta."&color=rojo"); 
   }
```

Si te estas preguntando, los valores de la base de datos estan bien escrito igual que la tabla, como les digo despues del execute me dice que lo hizo bien pero en la base de datos no paso nada.

Comment: Tu UPDATE es peligroso. Las  variables debes pasarlas en su orden. En la instrucción SQL el id del producto está de último, pero en el bind tú lo estás pasando de primero: `$producto->bindValue(1, $id);`  El valor que usará como `WHERE` en tu código será el valor de `$stock` que es el último. Si el código funciona podrías estar actualizando los registros con otro id... y fastidiar tus datos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que mencionas pasa normalmente cuando la consulta se ejecuta pero ninguna fila de la tabla cumple con las condiciones del where.

Por ello se ejecuta correctamente pero no cambia nada. Usa `rowcount` para saber si hubo filas afectadas.

`if ( $producto->execute() !== false && $producto->rowCount() > 0 )`

Ademas los parámetros se están pasando en el orden incorrecto.

Puedes hacer esto para asegurar ademas hace mas seguro el codigo:

```
 global $conn;
  $producto = $conn->prepare
  ("UPDATE productos SET nombre = :nombre, precio = :precio,
   marca = :marca, presentacion = :presentacion, stock = :stock WHERE idproducto = :idproducto");

  $producto->bindValue(':idproducto', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $producto->bindValue(':nombre', $nombre,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $producto->bindValue(':precio', $precio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $producto->bindValue(':marca', $marca, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $producto->bindValue(':presentacion', $presentacion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $producto->bindValue(':stock', $stock, PDO::PARAM_STR);

 if($producto->execute() !== false && $producto->rowCount() > 0)
  {
      $respuesta = "El articulo se actualizo con exito";
      header("location: ". BACK_END_URL ."/?rta=".$respuesta."&color=verde");
  }
 else
 {
     $respuesta = "El articulo no se actualizo con exito";
     header("location: ". BACK_END_URL ."/?rta=".$respuesta."&color=rojo"); 
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos! ahora estoy en el trabajo pero bien llego a mi casa lo prueba, son lo mas todos! si alguien mas tiene algo que me puede servir gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tu UPDATE es peligroso y aunque crees que no pase nada, puede que pase algo muy grave: que se estén actualizando los registros que no son.

Las variables debes pasarlas en su orden, más aún si estás usando `bindValue` con marcadores de **posición** (`?`).

He resaltado *posición* a propósito, porque aquí la *posición* es vital.

El [Manual dice](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) hablando del orden que se debe observar cuando usamos `bindValue` dice:

> Para sentencias preparadas que usen parámetros de sustición de signos
>   de interrogación, esto [el número usado con bindValue] será la posición índice-1 del parámetro.

Si tu consulta está escrita así:

```
$producto = $conn->prepare
("UPDATE productos SET nombre = ?, precio = ?,
 marca = ?, presentacion = ?, stock = ? WHERE idproducto = ?");
```

Y usas `bindValue` debes pasar los valores en este orden:

- nombre
- precio
- marca
- presentacion
- stock
- id_producto

Es decir:

> ```
> $producto->bindValue(1, $nombre);
> $producto->bindValue(2, $precio);
> $producto->bindValue(3, $marca);
> $producto->bindValue(4, $presentacion);
> $producto->bindValue(5, $stock);
> $producto->bindValue(6, $id);
> ```

Pero tú estás pasando primero, por lo que veo, el valor que debería corresponder a `id_producto`...

```
$producto->bindValue(1, $id);  //Este es el último ? de tu consulta ¿sí o no? No debería ser el 1º aquí
$producto->bindValue(2, $nombre);
$producto->bindValue(3, $precio);
$producto->bindValue(4, $marca);
$producto->bindValue(5, $presentacion);
$producto->bindValue(6, $stock);
```

Lo que ocurre aquí es que en tu `UPDATE` **nombre será igual a `$id`, precio será igual a nombre (o a cero, quien sabe), marca será igual a precio... y así**  y el registro que se actualizará será **el que tenga un `id_producto` igual a `$stock`**

Tu consulta si está funcionando, está actualizando los registros que no son. ¿Ves el peligro?

---

#### POST-DATA

Por si no lo sabías, con PDO puedes pasar totalmente de `bindValue`, creando un array con tus valores y **pasando ese array en el [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php)**.

Ejemplo:

```
   global $conn; //¿globales?... oh no
   $producto = $conn->prepare
    ("UPDATE productos SET nombre = ?, precio = ?,
     marca = ?, presentacion = ?, stock = ? WHERE idproducto = ?");

    /*array respetando el orden de cada valor*/
    $arrParams=array($nombre,$precio,$marca,$presentacion,$stock,$id);

    /*Pasamos el array en el execute*/
    if($producto->execute($arrParams))
    {
        $respuesta = "El articulo se actualizo con éxito. Filas afectadas:  ".$producto->rowCount();

        header("location: ". BACK_END_URL ."/?rta=".$respuesta."&color=verde");
    }
   else
   {
       $respuesta = "El articulo no se actualizo con exito";
       header("location: ". BACK_END_URL ."/?rta=".$respuesta."&color=rojo"); 
   }
```

Comment: Gracias chee,  me sirvio mucho pero de todas maneras no cambia nada, ya no se que hacer no se que estoy haciendo mal lo revise un millon de veces y no encuntro el porque consulta con el bildParm pasa lo mismo ??

Comment: @KurtLabras en el código de la POST-DATA puse esto: `$producto->rowCount()` para ver si realmente está actualizando algo. Si no funciona, revisa tu variable global `$conn`.  El uso de globales no es recomendado... si se anula en otro script ya no dispones de ella. Revisa también tu archivo `error_log`.